# How to delete pthreads?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I want use 5 threads on C++ program. I want create new thread when old ends working. How to implement it? How delete old threads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) for this purpose:

> The pthread_join() function shall suspend execution of the calling
>   thread until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread
>   has already terminated. On return from a successful pthread_join()
>   call with a non-NULL value_ptr argument, the value passed to
>   pthread_exit() by the terminating thread shall be made available in
>   the location referenced by value_ptr. When a pthread_join() returns
>   successfully, the target thread has been terminated. The results of
>   multiple simultaneous calls to pthread_join() specifying the same
>   target thread are undefined. If the thread calling pthread_join() is
>   canceled, then the target thread shall not be detached.

Comment: Thanks! But this means that (for example) my main threads will stopped and wait another thread. This is bad. Maybe I must use  pthread_detach(). What are the options?

Comment: @Gleb Dyachenko, if you do not want to block main thread, you can create a base thread in main to run your 5 threads in order. pthread_detech() has different functionality as far as I've read.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something of this sort,

- In main, create 5 threads (detached ones possibly).
- When a thread is about to terminate create a new detached thread 
  (and use a variable protected by a lock which indicates number of threads running
  currently, if its less than 5 create thread else exit) within the
  thread before exiting.

That way you will continuously create new threads.

[Detached threads](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_detach.html) run detached from other threads(main included), no one waits for them to complete their execution (They don't make a thread to stop executing). Whereas, when you use [`pthread_join(threadName,NULL)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) the thread calling this function has to wait until `threadName` has terminated. [Both, `pthread_detach` and `pthread_join` ensure the threads resources are released]

There is nothing like deleting pthreads.

Something this way,

```
static int count = 5;
pthread_mutex_t mutexForCount = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_attr_t attr;

void* tFn(void* arg)
{
    std::cout<<"\nI am "<<pthread_self();
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexForCount);
    count--;
    if(count<=5)
    {
        pthread_t temp;
        pthread_create(&temp,&attr,tFn,NULL);
        count++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexForCount);

}

int main()
{
pthread_t  threadArray[5];
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
    pthread_create(&threadArray[i],NULL,tFn,NULL);
}

for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
    pthread_join(threadArray[i],NULL);
}

pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

**Note:** The attribute and the mutex variables should be destroyed at the end of the program. I have assumed this program runs continuosly.

Answer (score 0):

The thread ends when the thread function exits.